# SSH remote command

Tags: ssh, command, remote-access

I have a strange SSH problem.
If I run this

```
ssh user@remote 'md5sum file.txt'
```

I get back the result as expected, but if I run this

```
ssh user@remote 'cat file.txt'
```

then it just sits there.

Comment: How large is file.txt and how long are you waiting while it "just sits there"?  If it's really large the output might be getting buffered, so you wouldn't see anything until there was around 4k bytes to write (your mileage may vary on the size of the buffer).

Comment: The file is couple of kB. I've been waiting for 10 minutes and didn't get anything back.

Comment: I also found out that while I can transfer a 50MB file to that remote machine using scp, I cannot do a simple
`ssh user@remote 'ls -al'` (when I press ENTER here nothing happens)

Comment: Can you run with `-vvvv` to get lots of verbose output and see if that has any clues?

Comment: I ran ´ssh user@remote 'ls MilkyWay*'´ (this one finished) and `ssh user@remote 'ls -al'` (this one does not finish) with `-vvvv`. The second command goes to `debug1: Sending command: ls -al`
`debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1`
`debug2: callback done`
`debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768`
`debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152`
`debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0`
`debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0`
 and then nothing else. I've waited for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll attribute this problems to bad network connection. I've started using [Mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/) and is works magnitudes better than ssh.